# How to use INTERVAL types in HSQL JRT function?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am trying to create a JRT function that accepts a parameter of type `INTERVAL`.
My query can provide any type of `INTERVAL` but I'd prefer to use `INTERVAL DAY` type if possible.

According to the [HSQL documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_routines), my function should look something like:

```java
public static String exampleHsqlFunction(final java.time.Period duration) {
    return "In example function, arg: " + duration.toString();
}
```

Then, the function needs to be registered. There is no `INTERVAL DAY` type specified in the table from documentation so I will use `INTERVAL MONTH` instead:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (duration INTERVAL MONTH)
RETURNS CHAR VARYING(100)
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:hsqltest.HsqlIntervalFunctionTest.exampleHsqlFunction';
```

So far so good, my function is registered properly and no errors are shown.

I will now create a dummy table so I have something to `SELECT` from when testing the function:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DUMMY(id INT); INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES (0);
```

Finally, I can try calling the function itself:

```sql
SELECT EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(INTERVAL '3' MONTH) FROM DUMMY;
```

aaand I'm getting an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

I did some debugging, put a breakpoint in `java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)` and it turns out that HSQL passes `org.hsqldb.types.IntervalMonthData` as argument to the method (or `org.hsqldb.types.IntervalSecondData` for `INTERVAL SECOND` type).

When the parameter type of Java method is changed to `IntervalMonthData`, however, HSQL is not able to recognize it:

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Java execution: unresolved class name, method name or signature

I also tried some silly stuff, such as passing `INTERVAL '3' DAY` as argument. Then the following exception is thrown:

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: interval field overflow

The function works if we change the parameter to some other type, for example `INT` and corresponding `Integer`. It's only `INTERVAL` that seems to be flaky.

I am using HSQL in version `2.5.0` (newest in Maven Central), minimal working example:

```java
package hsqltest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public final class HsqlIntervalFunctionTest {

    public static String exampleHsqlFunction(final java.time.Period duration) {
        return "In example function, arg: " + duration.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws SQLException {
        try (
            final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb",
                "sa",
                "sa"
            );
            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
        ) {
            // create function and link it to Java method
            statement.executeUpdate(
                "CREATE FUNCTION EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (duration INTERVAL MONTH)"
              + " RETURNS CHAR VARYING(100)"
              + " LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL"
              + " EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:hsqltest.HsqlIntervalFunctionTest.exampleHsqlFunction';"
            );

            // create dummy table so we have something to SELECT from
            statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE DUMMY(id INT);");
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES (0);");

            // use the function and print the result
            final ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(
                "SELECT EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(INTERVAL '3' MONTH) FROM DUMMY;"
            );
            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that the Java type mapping for INTERVAL types is invalid: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/HEAD/tree/base/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/types/Types.java#l624

Comment: Here is the mapping in `IntervalType`, the correct types are commented out for some reason: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/HEAD/tree/base/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/types/IntervalType.java#l152

Comment: These comments turn out to be a feature: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/building-app.html#bga_codeswitcher

Comment: Created a bug ticket in SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1564/